# Simogeo filemanager not returning image url to ckeditor

Tags: cakephp, ckeditor, file-manager, cakephp-2.6

I'm using ckeditor (version 4.4.7) and the Simogeo Filemanager (latest release) in the cakephp (2.6.3) framework.

CKeditor is showing the button for going to the filemanager. The filemanager is working fine but when I select a image nothing is happening. Normally the filemanager will close and the url to the image appears in the ckeditor image properties pop-up.

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<form>
     <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
         This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
    </textarea>
<script>
     CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'http://mywebsite/js/Filemanager-master', 
    });
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: Just tested right now. It seems to be ok. Have a closer look with firebug - maybe to get an error message ?

Comment: I checked firebug but there are no errors. If I click an image nothing seems to happen according firebug. Are there more setting to apply besides of the filemanager.config.js file?

Comment: Update afther using IE console: now I do receive a error: SCRIPT70: access denied. File: Filemanager-master, line: 23, column: 200

Comment: I'm not even sure it is the same issue. Any online url to provide ?

Comment: By the way, you can even try to run the script outside cakephp to see if the issue is related to the framework (I guess so)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The url to the filemanager: http://www.website.com/webroot/js/Filemanager-master/?CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=nl   Good tip: gone try it without cakephp framework.

Comment: Same problem outside cakephp.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of this answer but I didn't place the javascript for loading ckeditor in the header but in the body.
I made a clean page without any other javascripts and that was working.
@Simo May: thanks for the support